# Python function parameter as introspectable string

Tags: python, introspection

I'm currently building up a library of personal debugging functions, and wanted to make a debugging print function that would provide more quality-of-life functionality than adding `print(thing)` lines everywhere.  My current goal is to have this pseudocode function translated to Python:

```
def p(*args, **kwargs)
    for arg in args:
        print(uneval(arg), ": ", arg)
    return args
```

The types of `**kwargs` and how they'd effect the output isn't as important to this question, hence why I don't use them here.

My main problem comes from trying to have some method of `uneval`-ing the arguments, such that I can get the string of code that actually produced them. As a use case:

```
>>> p(3 + 5) + 1
3 + 5: 8 # printed by p 
9 # Return value of the entire expression
```

There's a couple of ways that I see that I can do this, and not only am I not sure if any of them work, I'm also concerned about how Pythonic any solution that actually implements these could possibly be.

1. Pass the argument as a string, `eval` it using the previous context's local identifier dictionary (how could I get that without passing it as another argument, which I definitely don't want to do?)
2. Figure out which line it's being run from in the .py file to extract the `uneval`'d strings that way (is that even possible?)
3. Find some metadata magic that has the information I need already in it (if it exists, which is unlikely at best).

Comment: you may use a decorator, that would use the `ast` module to parse the decorated function and from the produced syntax tree you may get your "uneval" function...

Comment: It sounds like you want to change the eval order. After all, the argument to p in your example is not '3 + 5'. You're not likely to be able to do that without source/token-level manipulation, essentially what you want is something macro-like. This is doable but it's hard to imagine any solution passing for 'pythonic'. It's just pure magic.

Comment: @pvg I'm fine with passing in `'3 + 5'` as my parameter as long as it can evaluate `'3 + 5'` in the same context I called `p` with.  In other words, if I have another parameter `args` in the context (let's call this `items`) that I'm calling `p`, I want my evaluation to use the `args` from `items` rather than the `args` from `p`'s definition.  If I can do that without passing in the local identifier dictionary directly, I'm happy.

Comment: @mguijarr I don't quite understand where the decorator would be placed here.  Around `p`, it's all but useless unless I'm missing something big; around the context I'm calling `p` in, I don't understand how I'd access it, and on top of all of that I'd like to be able to call `p` from outside of function definitions completely - say, in the REPL.

Comment: Just to double check here, `uneval` is something you're trying to get to, not something that exists and I haven't heard of?

Comment: That is correct. @pvg

Comment: Hmm yeah I don't think there's a particularly trivial way to do this at runtime without instrumenting the code or inserting yourself somewhere in the bowels of import (I think that's what some of the macro packages do). This seems both a hassle and enormously intrusive just for a marginally nicer debug printf.

Comment: @StevenHewitt: Indeed the decorator should be around `p` ; if I find some time I will try to make an answer ; but I am not certain I understand 100% your question ;)